# regex: Match atleast one character between two other characters

Tags: regex, language-packs

I currently use a regex

```
\\\[(.*)\\\]
```

so if I would try to match `[]` it will work. But what I want is so it requires at a minimum one character between `[` and `]` to match my regex, but how?

Thanks!

Comment: Replace `*` with `+`: `\\\[(.+)\\\]`

Comment: Hehe, thanks! I am a complete beginner with regular expressions!

Comment: I vote to close because you didn't bother to read a tutorial on regex or to search SO for similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before matching (.*). Do a match on [^]] to match something other than the closing ].